# How can I export Aptana color scheme in Eclipse

Tags: python, dictionary

I a using Aptana Studio inside  Eclipse Juno and I have also installed Eclipse color scheme plugin.

Now I have set up the Aptana theme with my custom colors and fonts.

Is there any way to export that Aptana color theme with all setting , color, sytanx , fonts so that i can export in new Eclipse Installation.

I could not find any export theme button.

In Eclipse , File menu options i can i see export options but only shows this

[image]